# .NET Core transitive Dependency for a .NET 4.6 Project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core

I have three .NET projects referencing each other like the following:

**AProject-> BProject-> CProject**, where A and B are Core projects and C is a .NET 4.6 project.

**AProject json** file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
   "net46": {
    "dependencies": {
    "ProjectB": {
      "target": "project" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**BProject json** file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
   "net46": {
    "dependencies": {
    "ProjectC": {
      "target": "project" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

NuGet restore and build work fine using Visual Studio, but NuGet restore using command line fails with the following error:

```
 Unable to resolve 'CProject' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6'
```

Remark: if i remove AProject from solution or if i change Cproject with another .NET core project, everything works fine. So the problem only occurs when we have a transitive dependency toward .NET 4.6 project.

**Environment :**

```
- NuGet Version: 3.5.0.1996
- Visual studio 2015
- .NET Core  1.0.1
```

Comment: What do you mean with .NET Core? Both A and B target `net46`, not `netstandard1.3`, so they are not .NET Core at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your question is not related to .NET Core at all, as your xproj files do still target `net46` and not `netstandard1.3` (or lower).

If your only issue is that you can't reference Project C, then you need to package ProjectC into a nuget package, setup a nuget source and add it to your NuGet.Config (http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/consume).

Or use Visual Studio 2017, which allows you to directly reference a 4.x *.dll inside the csproj (xproj and project.json being deprecated from now on).

Comment: Thank you @Tseng , 
 packaging project C is not an option for me , i am willing to configure the solution in a C.I server (Jenkins)

Comment: Another point : Assuming that i can't reference project C as you described , How can you explain the fact that restoring / building with VS works fine and using command line is failing ?

Comment: Packaging and hosting a nuget source can be done on CI too, it's just running a certain command on your ProjectC. Dunno why it appears to work for you at first, but that scenario is unsupported in project.json (http://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/184 and won't get fixed anyways, since it's deprecated and replaced with MSBuild compatible csproj now). You should (rather sooner than later) migrate to VS2017 and it's csproj based building pipeline. csproj support won't be comming for VS2015 and (ASP).NET Core 1.1 is the last version with project.json support

Comment: And since VS2017 is released in a few weeks and have full msbuild support. There is also no point in sticking with VS2015 anymore. Or you convert your ProjectC into xproject too. Little change. Most libraries do have had both, csproj and xproj with VS2015. One used to build the classic stuff and xproj for the newer project type

Comment: In the end i opt for creating a local NuGet repo, packaging project C, and handle it as a third party library , also i was able  to make it on CI server as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I could completely reproduced your problem in my environment.  NuGet restore package base on packages.config file, or a project.json file. NuGet will check the packages.config/project.json files in each projects when we restore the .sln file using NuGet command line.

For this structure AProject-> BProject-> CProject, NuGet will restore the packages for the Aproject base on the projectA.json. But only the dependencie “ProjectB” be defined in the ProjectA.json file, the dependencie “ProjectC” defined in the ProjectB.json file and ProjectC use packages.config to manage the nuge package. There must be some restrictions to on the conversion of information between project.json file and packages.config. So when restore the dependencie “ProjectC” base on the ProjectA.json file will get that error.

To resolve this issue, you can add the CProject as reference for AProject directly.